# Angular2 - how to write karma unit test case for checking maxlength for textbox?

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Need some insight on maxlength unit test case in Angular 2 with Karma

Comment: have you tried looking around in the oficial angular guide? -> https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: given your question, I assume you know how to write unit tests. If so, then after compiling your component, get the fixture. From that fixture get the input element by getElementsByTagName('input')[0]. Or if you have some id on that then getElementById(<id details>). Once you get the element use getComputedStyle to get the style. Of the result, get the value of style using getPropertyValue method

Comment: yes I have done that - but that is only property matching isn't it? I want to add actual string instead of hard coded mock vlaue - so is there any way to do it?